# How can I clean up "garbage" history entries from Terminal Remote Connection window?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, remote-desktop, defaults

When you press CMD+Shift+K on terminal, a **Remote Connection** window will appear, which allows you to save and manage your connections.
[image]

When I was trying to add the correct `ssh` command, I had several failed attempts. But Remote Connection saved all my wrong commands. It's now very confusing in the dropdown menu since there's tons of wrong hints.  I tried using the minus control (next to the plus sign) in the GUI to remove these - it was not successful to clean up the entries shown below the +/- controls.

- MacOS High Sierra, Version 10.13.6
- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)

Is there a way to remove the unwanted hints in the dropdown menu?

Comment: Have you minused out all the entries on the top right above the red section? I’d check each service - screen shot if you need to recreate anything. Then restart. Also - can you edit in what version of macOS if you want someone to try and reproduce this.

Comment: Even when I misused out all the entries inside the sever field, the drop down menu is still there. I have added my MacOs version already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application stores these previous commands in the defaults database. To clear these surgically, open a shell in Terminal.app and paste this and press return / enter.

```
defaults write "com.apple.Terminal" PreviousCommands '()'
```

You then quit the application to let it reload and read the defaults. I have tested this just now.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4184263

Comment: Apple, so user friendly!